# Apply two alternate rotations to a View in Android

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I'd like to apply 2 alternate rotation animations to a View. Each rotation should start after the click on the same View.

The result I'm looking for is:

- the user clicks on the View and it rotates from 0° to 135°
- the user clicks again on the View and it rotates from 135° to 0° (to the initial state)

The problem is that, when the user performs the second click, the Button resets to the initial aspect before starting the animation correctly.

I'm targeting Android APIs<11 so I'm using the startAnimation() method. The animations are applied to a Button view defined as follows:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The animations are the following

rotate_cw.xml (0° to 135° rotation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">

<rotate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="135" />

</set>
```

rotate_ccw.xml (135° to 0° rotation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<rotate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromDegrees="135"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="0"/>

</set>
```

The animations are then applied in this way, where flag is a boolean global variable:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (flag) {
            Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_cw);
            b.startAnimation(a);
        } else {
            Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_ccw);
            b.startAnimation(a);
        }
        flag = !flag;
    }
});
```

Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You probably want to add `fillEnabled="true"` and `fillBefore="true"` to your ccw rotation set.

Comment: I tried to add the two parameters either to the `set` or to the `rotate` element (or both of them) but the problem isn't fixed.

Comment: i do not recall which api level it was introduced but, check this out, after your animation, set your button rotation to the degree you rotated it, programmatically, `VIew.setRotation(rotation)` sounds legit?

Comment: @Elltz unfortunately the setRotation method was introduced in API 11